# Anchor tag underline is not aligning under text with highlight animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to have my anchor tag perform an animation where the underline highlights the text above upon hovering over it. Not sure why the underline is so far over to the left. Any ideas on what might be causing the issue?

I've tried changing the container class to be position: absolute and then set the content within as relative, but that didn't work either.

```css
.section-title {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 1.5%;
  font-size: 2em;
  transform: translateX(0%) translateY(-25%);
  /* z-index: -1; */
}

.section-title-highlight {
  color: black;
}

.section-title-highlight:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20%;
  background: #35FCCE;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: height .7s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.section-title-highlight:hover:before {
  height: 85%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: default;
  display: block;
}

.container {
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  padding-bottom: 7%;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
}

.container-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#home {
  height: 500px;
  /* margin-bottom: 0; */
  position: relative;
}

#projects {
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="projects">
    <a href="#" class="section-title-highlight section-title">Projects</a>
    <div class="container-item">
      <p>
        asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The transition doesn't appear to be working either - is that something you missed in the code above or is it just something you're still working on?

Comment: This `.section-title-highlight:before` has a width of 20%... Should that be 100%?

Comment: The width of the green box is not bound to the width of your text.
You can fix it by faking the text width in the box or by making the text a child of the box.

Comment: `position: absolute;` is probably more headache than it's worth

Comment: Salem, can you confirm exactly what you are trying to do? I've looked at your code and its not clear what the highlight is supposed to look like - is it supposed to be 20% as a starting point for the animation? Or full width to start? And where does the animation come into it?

Comment: @haelmic not when used in the right way. It's only problematic when its misused... which admittedliy is all too often :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten It absolutely has it's place. It takes the element out of the body hierarchy, and external objects ignore it.

Comment: Instead of aligning the box inside the text, maybe make the green box surround the text and have another box aligned to the top edge cover it half way by default that shrinks with the animation.

Comment: I meant to have the width set of `.section-title-highlight:before ` set to 100%. @FluffyKitten I'm trying to have the line under the text "Projects" grow taller so it appears as if it's highlighting it. I'm wondering if some of my other CSS is funking it up since it looks different here.

Comment: @haelmic how would I fake the text width in the box or make it a child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `position:absolute` on your highlight block, with places it in the exact position you specify, *relative to it's parent container that has* `position:relative`.

Your highlight should be relative to the text in the `section-title-highlight`, so you simply need to make it relative like this:

```
.section-title-highlight {
  position:relative;
}
```

Your highlight element is now being placed at the bottom left of the text:

```
.section-title-highlight:before {
  height: 2px;      /* or whatever your starting height should be */
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* rest of your css here... */ 
}
```

The other problem you have is that the **highlight is appearing much wider than the text**. This is because your title is a block element so it stretches the full width of its container.

You can fix that by making the highlight an `inline` or `inline-block` element. In the example below I have made your `section-title` a block element and left your `section-title-highlight` inline:

```
 <div class="section-title">
     <a class="section-title-highlight">Projects</a>
 </div>
```

**Working example:**

```css
.section-title {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 1.5%;
  font-size: 2em;
  transform: translateX(0%) translateY(-25%);
  /* z-index: 0; */
}

.section-title-highlight {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
}

.section-title-highlight:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 2px;  /* or whatever height you want to start */
  width: 100%;
  background: #35FCCE;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: height .7s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.section-title-highlight:hover:before {
  height: 85%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: default;
  display: block;
}

.container {
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  padding-bottom: 7%;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
}

.container-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#home {
  height: 500px;
  /* margin-bottom: 0; */
  position: relative;
}

#projects {
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="projects">

    <a href="#" class="section-title-highlight section-title">Projects</a>
      <p>The heading above is using a block display (as in your code), so it is appearing the full width of the container.</p>
    <div class="section-title">
      <span class="section-title-highlight">Projects</span>
    </div>
    <div class="container-item">
      <p>
        This heading is using an inline element so the highlight is only the width of the text
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so so much. I was going mad trying to figure this one thing out. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I got the result I believe you are looking for simply by changing this:

```
.section-title-highlight:before {
  width: 20%;
}
```

to this:

```
.section-title-highlight:before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

The discussion about "faking the text width" boils down to this: your `div.projects` width is determined by the width of your text. Your `a::before` width is determined by the width of `div.project`. Ergo, setting `a::before`'s `width` property to 100% sets it to the width of your text.

It is also necessary, as you have surmised, to absolutely position the `a::before` element. If you don't, it will be in the flow, take up 100% of its container, and then wrap your text onto the next row. If you try removing `position: absolute` from it this will be apparent to you.

Changing the container class to absolute and the element to relative only absolutely positions your container in the next element above it in the DOM tree (the "containership hierarchy," if that makes more sense) that is positioned relatively. So no, that wouldn't work.

Here's the code:

```css
    .section-title {
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 2em;
      text-align: center;
      padding-bottom: 1.5%;
      font-size: 2em;
      transform: translateX(0%) translateY(-25%);
      /* z-index: -1; */
    }

    .section-title-highlight {
      color: black;
    }

    .section-title-highlight:before {
      content: '';
      display: inline-block;
      height: 20px;
      width: 100%;
      background: #35FCCE;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      transition: height .7s;
      z-index: -1;
    }

    .section-title-highlight:hover:before {
      height: 85%;
    }

    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: default;
    }

    .container {
      padding: 3% 5% 7%;
      margin: 0 5% 5%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
    }

    .container-item {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    #projects {
      height: 600px;
      position: relative;
    }  

    .projects-header {
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div id="projects">
      <div class="projects-header">
        <a href="#" class="section-title-highlight section-title">Projects</a>
      </div>
      <div class="container-item">
        <p>
          Edit: the problem was that the highlight on the title would expand to be as wide as this paragraph, which was not apparent when only "asdf" was in it..
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Maybe a little clarification on `position` will be helpful. Default value for `position` is `static`. Statically positioned elements are placed wherever they occur in the page flow, as if they were paragraphs of text. A relatively positioned element is positioned relative to its static position, where `top` and `left` are offsets from the static position. So, if, say, you gave your `div.projects` a `top: -10px`, it would be positioned 10px higher than it would be if you didn't have any `position` value specified (i.e. the position type was static).

Absolutely positioned elements are positioned inside a relatively-positioned container, at `top: 0` and `left: 0` unless otherwise specified. So, it isn't strictly necessary for you to have a `top: 0` in your `a::before` style. You do have to have the `bottom: 0`, since otherwise your bar would be at the top of your text instead of the bottom.

#### Edit

The fix (well, my fix) for the problem that the OP and FluffyKitten describe in the comments required two steps.

1. The structure of the HTML was such that the anchor element was being treated as a flex cell. As such, its width was tied to the width of the paragraph. So, the first step is to wrap the anchor tag in a div. (Done as `div.project-header`.)
2. The anchor tag was in block display, meaning it takes up the entire width of its container. The fix to this was to change `display:block` in the `.section-title` style to `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Thank you! I have that set, but now the width is as long as the div instead of only being as wide as the text. Is there a way around that?

Comment: @Salem For me, they are the same width. Do you have a width specified for `#projects` that isn't in the code you shared, perhaps? I've put up my code so you can compare.

Comment: @BobRodes If you add more text to the container, you will see the problem. The OP described the problem but it wasn't obvious in the code because there wasn't enough text to stretch the container to full width. When more text in added to the container, it expands to its full width and you can see the problem more easily

Comment: @FluffyKitten Why thank you. Now I do see the problem. :) I'll have a look.

Comment: FYI, I edited the question so that we all could see the problem the OP was trying to describe (just in case you think you somehow missed it first time!) :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten Thanks. And fixed. :)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is not use your relative for anything other than the title and you'll be fine!

This uses the original code from the question and changes the width of the box shrinks the hight, and adds a margin-bottom transition.

```css
    .section-title {
      display: block;
      font-size: 2em;
      text-align: center;
      padding-bottom: 1.5%;
      font-size: 2em;
      transform: translateX(0%) translateY(-25%);
      /* z-index: -1; */
    }

    .section-title-highlight {
      color: black;
    }

    .section-title-highlight:before {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      height: 5px;
      width: 100%;
      background: #35FCCE;
      position: absolute;
      margin-bottom: .2em;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      transition: margin-bottom .5s , height .7s;
      z-index: -1;
    }

    .section-title-highlight:hover:before {
      height: 85%;
      margin-bottom:0;
    }

    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: default;
      display: block;
    }

    .container {
      padding-top: 3%;
      padding-left: 5%;
      padding-right: 5%;
      padding-bottom: 7%;
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-left: 5%;
      margin-right: 5%;
      margin-bottom: 5%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
    }

    .container-item {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    #home {
      height: 500px;
      /* margin-bottom: 0; */
      position: relative;
    }

    #projects {
      height: 2em;
      position: relative;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div id="projects">
        <a href="#" class="section-title-highlight section-title">Projects</a>
        <div class="container-item">
        </div>
      </div>
      <p>
            asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
          </p>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't fix the problem where the highlight stretches the full width of the container  -the OP described it in the question but it wasn't obvious in the code. When more text in added to the container, it expands to its full width and you can see the problem more easily.

Comment: @FluffyKitten does this help?